# Information about usage of informed

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say : "It is informed to all"?

At times people mention it very freely that "It is informed to all the participants". This usage does not appear to be correct for the word of "informed".

Comment: No, it isn't correct. They should say "It is announced to all participants" or "All participants are informed".

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct because the object of *inform* is the person being told, not the fact which is imparted.

The passive voice transforms a sentence in such a way that the object of the active-voice becomes the *patient* in the passive. For example, with the transitive verb *paint:*

> I painted the fence.
>   → The fence was painted [by me].

For *inform,* the object is the person being told:

> I informed him that...
>   I informed him of...
>   → He was informed that/of...

For a passive construction of "It was informed to all," the object should be *it,* but as that's the *dummy it,* to do so makes no sense. That sentence can't be converted into the active voice:

> He was informed that...
>   → [Someone] informed him that...
>
> It was informed to all that...
>   → [Someone] informed [??]

There isn't anything to go in the object position in that last example. Even if one were to argue, "Well, it's *all* or *everyone* or something," then making that form into the passive should end up with the original:

> [Someone] informed everyone ...
>   → Everyone was informed ...

You don't end up with "It was informed to all" and so "It was informed to all" must be an incorrect construction.

Answer (score 0):

The expression "it is informed to all" is a lopsided passive voice.It is always better to use the active voice for clarity. For instance, while both of these expressions are correct: "They told Joe the truth" and "Joe was told the truth", the first one is better. In this sense, it may be better to say: We inform all (people) that ... or We notify all that ...
Thank you.

Comment: The passive voice is responsible for much muddled writing, but the passive has its uses. The advice that it's "always better to use the active" is bad advice. Even in your example. If Joe is the focus of the narrative, *Joe was told the truth* might be better, especially if the tellers are unknown or not to be mentioned for some other reason.  *It is informed* is unidiomatic for reasons unrelated to voice.